# Docker run Error: /bin/sh: 1: python: not found

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

So, im trying to learn docker and tried making a simple image to try it out. The docker build part goes well but when I docker run, I get a problem:

```
(base) daniellombardi@Daniels-MacBook-Pro MyApp-test % docker run bd
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

RUN pip3 install flask

RUN mkdir /MyApp-test

ADD folder /opt/MyApp-test

EXPOSE 5000

CMD python .main.py
```

and for anyone wondering, this is the code on main.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'IT WORKED! I AM RUNNING FROM A DOCKER CONTAINER!!!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Comment: change to `CMD python3 .main.py`

Comment: I get this error:
```
(base) daniellombardi@Daniels-MacBook-Pro MyApp-test % docker run 3bd
python3: can't open file '.main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you are only install `python3` inside the docker image as shown here

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip`

So you will need to run `python3` instead of `python` in this line: `CMD python .main.py`

And you have a typo in the script name. It should be `main.py` instead of `.main.py`. Or it should be `./main.py`

So change it to `CMD python3 ./main.py`

And if you still have error, you probably need to add this line in the `Dockerfile` above line of `EXPOSE 5000`:

`WORKDIR /opt/MyApp-test`

Comment: this error shows up:
`(base) daniellombardi@Daniels-MacBook-Pro MyApp-test % docker run 3bd
python3: can't open file '.main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: you should use `python3 ./main.py` instead of `python3 .main.py`